# Dynamics CRM - Missing components while importing solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an issue with importing solution. First of all i will explain my method of importing.

In our organisation we have all the solutions in source control (Extracted by solution packager as Both - Managed and Unmanaged). thanks to that we can build Managed or UnManaged Package from those files.

I have three solutions: Solution_1, Solution_2 and Solution_3. Solution_3 is dependent from 1 and 2. We decided to merge solution 1 and 2 in one solution, lets say Solution_12. Now is the problem:

When i am importing Solution_12 and Solution_3 as Managed, all works fine. When i am importing Solution_12 as Managed and Solution_3 as unmanaged, also all is fine. The probe occurs when I am importing Solution_12 as unmanaged and Solution_3 as Managed. In this situation Solution_3 cannot be imported:

The import of the solution Solution_3 failed. The following components are missing in your system and are not included in the solution. Import the managed solutions that contain these components (Solution_12 (1.0.0.5)) and then try importing this solution again.

*Required components are existing in organisation in Solution_12 but when importing they are unavaiable somehow.*

Anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a solution. The key was that any Managed solution cannot be dependant from Unmanaged solution.